# Suitability of "abstract" for describing an "alternative message to a long text"

Tags: etymology

I would like to know whether using the word *abstract* is suitable for describing a message going along with a longer text. I know in academia it is used for something very specific, but I'm more interested in its etymological value rather than its conventional.

This is for an application I'm making where there is a long text and then the author can provide a shorter text functioning as:

- some parallel short message
- short summary
- essence of the text.

I hope the question make sense.

Comment: The question makes sense; the title doesn't.

Comment: 'I would like to know whether using the word _abstract_ is suitable for describing a message going along with a longer text' conflicts with 'I'm more interested in its etymological value rather than its conventional'. Modern usage determines acceptability.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm aware of the argument that modern day usage determines acceptability. I'm not convinced about that, but it is off-topic to analyse it. I'm seeking _suitability_ on an etymological level. I don't find anything conflicting there.

Comment: Even if a 300-year-old meaning fits, it's not suitable unless it's still in use. Unless you mean 'suitable for the purposes of confusing / appearing eccentric / giving a period flavour'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For *short summary* or *essence of*, you might try **precis**:

> › a short form of a text that gives only the important parts:
>
> You have all been given a précis of the report. - *[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/precis)*

Does **commentary** suit your need for a parallel text?

> A set of explanatory or critical notes on a text: [a commentary on the
> Old Testament] - *[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commentary)*

Comment: I've edited the answer, adding a a word for (possibly) a parallel text.

Answer (score 1):

For "summary and essence", *abstract* would be applicable.  For a "short message" about the longer text, not.

P.S. If you're looking for a label that is broad enough to accommodate almost any kind of brief snippet of text (and is therefore almost meaningless as a descriptor)  *blurb* might do.

Comment: _Blurb_ is a valid word for this. Considering it.

Answer (score 1):

You cab use *excerpt*:

> a passage or quotation taken or selected from a book, document, film, or the like; extract. ([Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/excerpt))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word "***annotation***" as a broad term to describe all kinds of notes and comments pertaining to the main text.

Comment: Annotation is similar to the word "commentary" suggested by @Margana. Quite suitable.

Answer (score -1):

**Preface** would allow the author to decide what sort of introduction, summary, blurb to add

> **Preface**  2:  the introductory remarks of a speaker or author
>   (**[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preface)**)

**Abstract**  (**a**, **ab**, **abs**, from; **-tract**, < traho, draw/drag) etymologically can mean to take a chunk from the original, or to take the essence from it. It's pushing it to describe an apology for the paper, or a history, or a welcome as "**an abstract.**"

Comment: When I _transfer_ what _abstract_ does does for papers, I find it very suitable for my application. The essence and the apology. I don't understand why your contribution hasn't been more up voted.

Comment: 'Abstract' combines three ideas, that it is not the main paper but accompanies it, that the addition is made by the author of the main contribution( or at least not a critic), and that it is serious. Definitely the best alternative. Preface is a bit bookish, but less specific.